# KSoap2 Parse from String in Android

Tags: android, xml

I have a XML string that I need to parse, no need to go for HTTP Request or anything. Network is not required, I have tried SAX but it's super slow. I have tried ksoap2 with http and I find it really good. Following is my XML Example (Soap envelope is trimmed).

```
<ArrayOfEpisodes>
<RecentEpisodes>
    <Episode>
        <Views>Int</Views>
        <MediaList>
            <TVEpisodeMedia>
                <MediaURL>http://</MediaURL>
                <MediaType>String</MediaType>
            </TVEpisodeMedia>
        </MediaList>
        <Id>Int</Id>
        <Title>String</Title>
    </Episode>
    <Drama>
        <LikeCount>Int</LikeCount>
        <CommentCount>Int</CommentCount>
        <Views>Int</Views>
        <Id>Int</Id>
        <Name>String</Name>
    </Drama>
</RecentEpisodes></ArrayOfEpisodes>
```

the above XML is in string and I need to parse it using KSoap2

Thanks

Comment: "I have tried SAX but it's super slow" -- when you used Traceview to determine where your problem is, what did you learn? "I need to parse it using KSoap2" -- where do you see that kSOAP2 is capable of serving as a general XML parser? According to the project site, it is a "lightweight and efficient SOAP client library", which is not the same as being a general XML parser.

Comment: The xml that I have paste is soap response i have trimmed the envelope.

Comment: DOM is faster than SAX in parsing small xml file. You can try that.